# Overriding ReportViewer CSS (SP 2010)

Tags: css, report-viewer

I have an SSRS report which displays fine when viewed as a standalone report. However, when viewed via a reportviewer web part the formatting changes and the report looks awful. I believe this is to do with the CSS that is automatically applied for reportviewer. I want to override this but not sure exactly what I need to override. I've managed to improve the chart display by editing the css properties for img but I'm not sure what else I need to change. The report is 'squashed' - text which should appear on a single line rolls over to a second line.

Is there a way to override all the css that is automatically applied? Or can someone advise what specific css I may need to override?